# How to add a C# class object to an Entity table using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How to add a class object to an Enitity table using LINQ???The prescriber object is built from FullMasters Entity but I need to take that object and save it to EPCS_Prescriber table. I'm using linq.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    SourceofTruthEntities context = null;
    ePrescribeEntities epcs = null;

    public UserRepository()
    {
        context = new SourceofTruthEntities();
    }

    public List<FullMaster> SelectByNPI(string id)
    {
        var data = context.FullMasters.Where(x => x.NPI == id).ToList();
        return data;
    }

    public List<FullMaster> SelectByName(string first, string last)
    {
        var data = context.FullMasters.Where(x => x.FirstName == first && x.LastName == last).ToList();
        return data;
    }

    public void SavePrescriber(string id)
    {
        var data = context.FullMasters.Where(x => x.NPI == id).FirstOrDefault();

        Prescriber p = new Prescriber
        {
            First = data.FirstName,
            Last = data.LastName,
            DEA = data.DEA,
            License = data.LIC,
            Life = data.Life_Hosp,
            NPI = data.NPI
        };


        epcs.EPCS_Prescriber.Add(p);
        epcs.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

Comment: Also be aware that `data` could be null...

Comment: epcs.EPCS_Prescriber.AddObject(p);

Comment: epcs.EPCS_Prescriber.Add(p);  epcs.SaveChanges();

Comment: What assembly do i have to reference for Add method?

Comment: What exactly are your problems? Doesn't compile, exception when run, doesn't save? Please add any errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your contexts need initialization:

```
public UserRepository()
{
    context = new SourceofTruthEntities();
    ePrescribeEntities epcs = new ePrescribeEntities();
}
```

Comment: Yes I see both context have been initalized but I am taking a class object and trying to save it to a table entity and Im getting this error. Is there a way to cast?Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<ePrescribe.Domain.Entities.Data.EPCS_Prescriber>.AddObject(ePrescribe.Domain.Entities.Data.EPCS_Prescriber)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You can only add ePrescribe.Domain.Entities.Data.EPCS_Prescriber to your EPCS_Prescriber entities. You need to fill EPCS_Prescriber class with data and save that instead of your own Prescriber class.

Comment: Instead of _Prescriber p = new Prescriber_ do *EPCS_Prescriber p = new EPCS_Prescriber* if possible.

Comment: And make sure the set _System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<ePrescribe.Domain.Entities.Data.EPCS_Prescriber_ is part of the context in the first place. If you added the table to the database manually after the context was created, you need to update the context too.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void SavePrescriber(string id)
    {
        var data = context.FullMasters.Where(x => x.NPI == id).FirstOrDefault();


        EPCS_Prescriber e = new EPCS_Prescriber();
        e.FirstName = data.FirstName;
        e.LastName = data.LastName;
        e.DeaNo = data.DEA;
        e.License = data.LIC;
        e.LifeNo = data.Life_Hosp;
        e.NpiNo = data.NPI;

        epcs.EPCS_Prescriber.AddObject(e);
        epcs.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: I recommend to call await epcs.SaveChangesAsync() instead of epcs.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `epcs` is the db context, then you should use `epcs.EPCS_Prescriber.Insert(p)` rather than `AddObject(p)`

Comment: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<ePrescribe.Domain.Entities.Data.EPCS_Prescriber>' does not contain a definition for 'Insert' and no extension method 'Insert' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<ePrescribe.Domain.Entities.Data.EPCS_Prescriber>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Unless this isn't one database, surely you just need one context here? This should work for you:

```
public void SavePrescriber(string id)
{
    var data = context.FullMasters.Where(x => x.NPI == id).FirstOrDefault();

    Prescriber p = new Prescriber
    {
        First = data.FirstName,
        Last = data.LastName,
        DEA = data.DEA,
        License = data.LIC,
        Life = data.Life_Hosp,
        NPI = data.NPI
    };

    context.EPCS_Prescribers.Add(p);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Make sure your ...DbContext class contains the following:

```
...
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<YourNamespace.Models.Prescriber> EPCS_Prescribers { get; set; }
...
```

Check the names of the classes/entities if necessary.